# Prove uniform convergence if continuous and converge uniformly on a dense set

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

If $A \subset E \subset \mathbb{R}$, then $A$ is dense in $E$ in case $E = \overline{A} \bigcap E$. Assume$\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of functions continuous on $E$ and converging uniformly on a set $A$ dense in $E$.  Prove that $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ converges uniformly on $E$.

For this I am confused on how I am using dense and continuity to find uniform convergence. My idea it that I am somehow fix an $x$ and show cauchy criterion for $f_n(x)$ and that for every $x \in E$ and $a \in A$, $|x-a|$ can be made small. Thus $|f_n(x) - f_m(x)|$ can be shown to be $< \epsilon$ by using the add and subtract trick.

Can someone help me refine this and explain why?

Comment: If $|f_m(x)-f_n(x)|>\epsilon$, using the continuity of $f_m-f_n$, you can choose $c\in A$ with $|f_m(c)-f_n(c)|>\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use the fact that if $A\subseteq E$  is dense in $E$ and $g$ is a continuous on $E$ function, then $\sup_{x\in A}g(x) = \sup_{x\in E}g(x)$. In your case you'd need to apply this to $g$ being  a certain difference.

Comment: I guess this is a generalization of this result:
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Uniformly_Convergent_Sequence_on_Dense_Subset
of which I can't find a good reference